# java Paint component declaring shape and size outside of paintcomponent

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;



public class Panel  extends JPanel implements ActionListener   {


    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    public Panel(){

        t.start();
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();

    }
}
```

I want to set the shape and size of my graphic outside of the paint component, but I don.t know how to. I have tried Oval o = new Oval but it doesn't work please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "shape and size of my graphic"?

Comment: When i do paintcomponent i would do g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100); i want the shape oval and the size 100,100 to be declared outside paintcommponent so it can just draw the graphics in paintcomponent declaring the size and shape outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jason's solution will work, but if you want to move further, you can use the `java.awt.Shape` interface for abstraction, so that your `paintComponent` method does not need to know what it's painting.

```
private java.util.List<Shape> shapesToFill = new ArrayList<>();

public Panel(java.util.List<Shape> shapes) {
    this.shapesToFill.addAll(shapes);
    //...
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    shapesToFill.forEach(g2d::fill);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
    Ellipse2D.Double oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         g.fill(oval);
    }
```

Then you could just fill it in with g2D

Comment: how would i fill oval i tried g.add(oval); and g.filloval;

Comment: You're using Graphics, if you want to fill you have to use Graphics2D, so you'd replace your paintComponent with Graphics2D g instead of Graphics G. Then you'd write g.fill(oval). Other option is to do : g.fillOval(oval.x, oval.y, oval.width, oval.height);

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class Panel
        extends JPanel
        implements ActionListener {

      Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

      Oval oval = new Oval(0, 0, 50, 100);

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(oval.getX(), oval.getY(), oval.getWidth(), oval.getHeight());
      }

   static class Oval {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Oval(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
    }

    public int getX() {
      return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
      return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
      return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
      return height;
    }
  }
```